# SQL role playing game -- Classes table referencing a skills table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I've been working on a wordpress plugin that is designed to create a character for a wordpress user using MYSQL. I'm new to php and sql. I'm currently struggling with two tables in my DB. A class table and a skill table.

The class table is comprised of the different classes a character can be. For example; a Warrior, Paladin or Wizard.

The skills table is comprised of different skills a character can use. For example; lightning bolt, slay, or heal.

I want these tables to have a relation with each other. Only certain skills from the skills tabled can be used by a class from the class table. So for example, a Paladin class can only choose the heal skill and a Warrior class can only use the slay skill. I'm just not sure what to use to make that work successfully.

I'm not sure if there's a condition that can be used on the skills table that only allows a certain class to reference certain skills. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If only one class can have a skill you can just add class_id as a fk in the skill table. If multiple classes can have the same skill you need a class_skill table with a class_id fk and a skill_id fk which you use to set which class can have which skills

Comment: Sounds like you want to use what is called a "many-to-many" relationship. That involves creating an intermediate table that would link your two tables. Just google sql many to many example and lots should come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship will do the trick here, this is what I would do.
I would create 3 tables, 1) Character 2) Skill 3) character_skill, here is a very simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE hero
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE skill
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE character_skill
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    charachter_id INT,
    skill_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT character_skill_character_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (charachter_id) REFERENCES hero (id),
    CONSTRAINT character_skill_skill_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (skill_id) REFERENCES skill (id)
);
```

Now you will store the characters on the hero table, and the skills on the skill table, now here is the trick, to assign a hero(Character) a skill you will add a record to the character_skill table with the id of the hero and the id of the skill.  In the example I added a constraint that will only allow you to add characters and skills that where previously created in the other tables.

Then to query it, I will look for all the Skills on the character_skill table that have the same charachter id, liks so:

```
select
  skill.name
from skill
INNER JOIN character_skill
  on character_skill.skill_id = skill.id
where character_skill.charachter_id = 3
```

This is a very simple example.

This is the basic idea, only the skills connected in the character_skill table can be use by  character with id 3

- I used hero for the name of the character table because the 'character' name is reserved

Comment: I believe I understand, so the character_skill table is basically a cross reference table which constrains certain classes from picking certain skills.

Comment: Yup than is correct, you can cross reference the skills with the character. Hope it works for you ;-)